# Java error creating subclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

I trying to learn some Java and I've got stuck creating a subclass. I keep getting a `There is no default constructor available in...` error.

This is the code:

```
class Car 
{
    String name;
    int speed;
    int gear;
    int drivetrain;
    String direction;
    String color;
    String fuel;

    public Car(String carName, int carSpeed, String carDirection, String carColor, int carDriveTrain, int carGear)
    {
        name = carName;
        speed = carSpeed;
        gear = carGear;
        drivetrain = carDriveTrain;
        direction = carDirection;
        color = carColor;
        fuel = "Gas";
    }

    void shiftGears(int newGear){gear = newGear; }
    void accelerateSpeed(int acceleration){speed = speed + acceleration;  }
    void applyBrake(int brakingFactor){ speed = speed - brakingFactor;}
    void turnWheel(String newDirection){ direction = newDirection; }

}//end of Car class

class Suv extends Car
{

    void applyBrake(int brakingFactor)
    {
        super.applyBrake(brakingFactor);
        speed = speed - brakingFactor;

    }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to create the "Suv" subclass. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a constructor in `Suv` which gets the same parameters as `Car`.

Comment: Long story short, that's not how classes in Java work.

Comment: You don't need "super.", you have to declare your methods protected. Not having a public/private/protected identifier makes them be visible only at package level.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM Most of what you have said is not true. You _can_ have multiple classes per file. Subclasses do _not_ have to be "declared as static". Method privacy is unrelated to anything in the question.

Comment: @khelwood is right - and it's worth expending your comment: there can be only one **public** class per file, but there can be multiple non-public classes.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. What it is frustrating is that I used the code exactly as it appeared in the book I'm using to learn "Android Apps for Absolute Beginners, Third Edition". Nonetheless I get this error.

Comment: }//end of Car class

class Suv extends Car
{

@khelwood that idiom he wrote is wrong unless split in several files. Dunno where the static comment came from, I was mistaken. Maybe because it's a code smell I don't use, but it's feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to create the following constructor in `Suv` that initialzies that parameters that the `Car` constructor has:

```
public Suv(String carName, int carSpeed, String carDirection, String carColor, int carDriveTrain, int carGear)
{
    super (carName, carSpeed, carDirection, carColor, carDriveTrain,carGear);
}
```

The alternative is to add the parameterless constructor to `Car`, in which case the default constructor of `Sub` would call that constructor :

```
public Car()
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since "Car" has a constructor, any subclass derived from Car needs a constructor as well. So first you need to put a constructor in the Suv class.

Example:

```
class Suv extends Car {
    public Suv() {
        super( /* here you need to pass arguments to create a car */);
        // any other constructor code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following constructor to `Car`:

```
public Car(){}
```

The problem is that `Suv` cannot be created since in order to run `Suv`'s default constructor the constructor of `Car` needs to be ran first, and `Car` has only a constructor that accepts arguments so it can't be used as default-constructor.

Another approach would be, as @Markus suggested, to implement a constructor in `Suv` that'll call `super` with all the required arguments. Either way, the main idea is that in order to instantiate `Suv` we need to be able to instantiate `Car` first otherwise we'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is to not put the SUV class in the same file. Instead, Create another class in your current package, name it SUV, extended it and call the superclass constructor by either of the following two syntax:

```
super(); //calls the superclass no-argument constructor with no parameter list
```

or

```
super(parameter list); //calls the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list
```